# Use OR instead of AND in the validation

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a `user` where I want to make sure that a `user` has at least a `first_name` or a `last_name` or a `nickname`. The `user` doesn't have to have all fields. Just one is enough. The default code provides validation for all fields only. How can I rewrite it to check for an OR instead of an AND?

```elixir
defmodule Vutuv.User do
  use Vutuv.Web, :model

  schema "users" do
    field :first_name, :string
    field :last_name, :string
    field :nickname, :string

    timestamps
  end

  @required_fields ~w(first_name last_name nickname)
  @optional_fields ~w()

  @doc """
  Creates a changeset based on the `model` and `params`.

  If no params are provided, an invalid changeset is returned
  with no validation performed.
  """
  def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
    model
    |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to first move all the fields from `@required_fields` to `@optional_fields`:

```elixir
@required_fields ~w()
@optional_fields ~w(first_name last_name nickname)
```

Then, use a custom validator in `changeset/2`:

```elixir
def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
  model
  |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
  |> validate_first_name_or_last_name_or_nickname(params)
end

def validate_first_name_or_last_name_or_nickname(changeset, :empty) do
  changeset
end

def validate_first_name_or_last_name_or_nickname(changeset, _) do
  first_name = get_field(changeset, :first_name)
  last_name = get_field(changeset, :last_name)
  nickname = get_field(changeset, :nickname)

  if first_name || last_name || nickname do
    # No error if any of those 3 are present.
    changeset
  else
    # All the 3 fields are nil.
    message = "first_name or last_name or nickname must be present"
    changeset
    |> add_error(:first_name, message)
    |> add_error(:last_name, message)
    |> add_error(:nickname, message)
  end
end
```